# How to construct a numpy array with multilple same timestamp?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, timestamp

I have tried:

```
import numpy as np
t = np.full((10),'2012-12-10', dtype=np.datetime64)
```

But got such an error:

```
ValueError: Cannot create a NumPy datetime other than NaT with generic units
```

Do you have any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I figured it out, you must fully specify the datatype for datetime objects

Do this

```
np.full((10), '2012-12-10', dtype='datetime64[D]')

array(['2012-12-10', '2012-12-10', '2012-12-10', '2012-12-10',
       '2012-12-10', '2012-12-10', '2012-12-10', '2012-12-10',
       '2012-12-10', '2012-12-10'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

My previous answer is below

---

Hm, not sure why np.full does not work in that case specifically. However one way to achieve this is to instead use `np.tile`

```
np.tile(np.array(['2012-12-10'], dtype=np.datetime64), 10)

array(['2012-12-10', '2012-12-10', '2012-12-10', '2012-12-10',
       '2012-12-10', '2012-12-10', '2012-12-10', '2012-12-10',
       '2012-12-10', '2012-12-10'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
```